# Авторизация и дальнейшая работа с сайтом

Tags: c#

Написал программу, которая должна входить на mail.ru и после сохранения куки работать на сайте aw.mail.ru. Вход успешный на mail.ru, но при другом запросе вылетает ошибка "Запрос не выполнен. Запрос отменен." Проверял через фидлер и другие программы, показывает Connect:close. Помогите найти ошибку что не так написал в коде, работаю не так давно с System.Net.

```
public static string Key(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            var cc = new CookieContainer();
            string log = String.Format( "Page=https%3A%2F%2Faw.mail.ru%2F&Login={0}&Domain=mail.ru&Password={1}&saveauth=1", "login", "password" );
            HttpWebRequest reqst = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create( "https://auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth" );
            reqst.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
            reqst.Method = "Post";
            reqst.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            reqst.Referer = "https://aw.mail.ru/";
            reqst.CookieContainer = cc; // Cookies
            reqst.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] encod = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(log);
            reqst.ContentLength = encod.Length;
            using ( Stream stream = reqst.GetRequestStream() )
            {
                stream.Write( encod, 0, encod.Length );
                stream.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse resp = ( HttpWebResponse ) reqst.GetResponse();

            if(resp.Cookies.Count == 0)
            {
                CookieException ex = null;
                MessageBox.Show( ex.Message );
            }
            else
            {
                foreach(Cookie c in resp.Cookies)
                {
                    cc.Add( c );
                }
                string post2 = String.Format( "pin={0}&activate=1", key);
                HttpWebRequest reqst2 = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create( "https://aw.mail.ru/dynamic/pin/?a=activate" );
                reqst2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
                reqst2.Method = "Post";
                reqst2.Referer = "https://aw.mail.ru/pin/";
                reqst2.KeepAlive = true;
                reqst2.Accept = "text/html, */*; q=0.01";
                reqst2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                reqst2.Headers.Add( HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-RU" );
                reqst2.Headers.Add( HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip" );
                reqst2.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                reqst2.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                reqst2.CookieContainer = cc; // Cookies


                byte[] encod2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( post2 );
                reqst2.ContentLength = encod.Length;
                reqst2.GetRequestStream().Write( encod2, 0, encod2.Length );
                reqst2.GetRequestStream().Close();
                    //stream2.Write( encod2, 0, encod2.Length );
                    //stream2.Close();
                    //stream2.Dispose();


                HttpWebResponse resp2 = ( HttpWebResponse ) reqst2.GetResponse();
                CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
                cookies = resp2.Cookies;
                Encoding responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding( resp.CharacterSet );
                using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( resp2.GetResponseStream(), responseEncoding ) )
                {
                    string res = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    //reader.Close();
                    resp.Dispose();
                    //if()
                    MessageBox.Show(res);
                }
            }

        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам отвечаю на свой вопрос. Сделал вот и все заработало

```
using ( var reqst = new HttpRequest() )
            {
                var cookie = new CookieDictionary();

                HttpResponse resp;
                reqst.Referer = "https://aw.mail.ru/pin/";
                reqst.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                reqst.UserAgent = HttpHelper.IEUserAgent();
                reqst.Cookies = new CookieDictionary()
                            {
                                {"key","value"}
                            };

                var param = new RequestParams();
                param["pin"] = key;
                cookie = reqst.Cookies;
                resp = reqst.Post( "https://aw.mail.ru/dynamic/pin/?a=activate", param );
                MessageBox.Show( resp.ToString() );

            }
```

Comment: А в чём была проблема?

Comment: Была проблема, что при другом запросе писал что я не авторизован, с куками не правильно что то написал, вообщем не передал куки на другой запрос, сделал через xNet и все пошло нормально.